# NodeJS and Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I've been searching for a solution for the past two days and can't figure it out. I have a node app that is using socket io living under a subdomain which is under a couple of folders `https://my.example.com/node/app1/` Every time I go to the URL I get
`GET https://my.example.com/socket.io/socket.io.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined`

Here's what my files look like:
nginx config file:

```
server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name my.example.com;

        include /etc/nginx/include.d/ssl-common;
        include /etc/nginx/include.d/ssl-example;

        include /etc/nginx/include.d/all-common;

        root /var/example/my;

        location /node/app1/ {
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3131;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/ssl_example_com.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }

        access_log /var/virdisoft/logs/access.log;
        error_log /var/virdisoft/logs/error.log;
}
```

app.js

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(3131, function() {
  console.log('Listening on 3131');
});

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:3131');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: In `index.html`, update script tag that should like `<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: @ArifKhan I've tried doing that before but was still getting an error. This is what I get in the console log: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () https://my.example.com/node/app1/socket.io/socket.io.js Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have finally figured it out, using your guys suggestions this is what I came up with: Please note the domain: example.com is a placeholder, so change exmaple.com and my.example.com to whatever your domain name is.

NGINX Config:

```
upstream my_nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:3131;
}

server {

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name my.example.com;

        include /etc/nginx/include.d/ssl-common;
        include /etc/nginx/include.d/ssl-example;

        include /etc/nginx/include.d/all-common;

        root /var/example/my;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/ssl_example_com.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }


        location ^~ /node/app1/ {
                try_files $uri @my_nodejs;
        }

        location ^~ /socket.io/ {
                try_files $uri @my_nodejs;
        }

        location @my_nodejs {
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://my_nodejs;
        }


        access_log /var/example/logs/access.log;
        error_log /var/example/logs/error.log;
}
```

app.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(3131, function() {
  console.log('Listening on 3131');
});

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io(); // Removed the path cause it's not needed.
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess you're receiving that error in the front-side, probably the browser is looking for `socket.io` in `http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js` instead of `http://localhost/node/app1/socket.io/socket.io.js`

Make sure to use a relative import:

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've tried doing that before but was still getting a error. This is what I get in the console log: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () https://my.example.com/node/app1/socket.io/socket.io.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined`

Comment: Try hardcoding the entire path with `localhost`, I don't think you own `my.example.com`. Make sure you're serving `socket.io` properly. You can also use a CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io

Comment: Tried setting it to http://localhost:3131/socket.io/socket.io.js but going to the site it couldn't connect to localhost. Tried setting it to the cdn as well but kept getting mixcontent. Changed everything to https and set the nodejs to support https but every time I went to the site it kept getting timed out.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to keep remain `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` and add another `location` directive for `socket.io`. You may bellow `location /node/app1/ {` in your nginx config file

```
location /socket.io {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3131;
}
```

Comment: Tried that but didn't work, kept getting the original error.